# Python Pygame ship move slowly when add alien in screen

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to write a pygame game where you shoot the alien.

first part I add the ship and bullet, it worked well, then I do the second part, add the alien onto the screen, but it some problems

before adding alien in-screen everything works correct, but when I import `alien.py` into the scripts, the ship moves really slowly almost can't move, what could be the problem?

in book using `aliens.draw(screen)` and i use `for alien in aliens.sprites: setting.screen.blit(alien.alien,alien.alien_rect)`

what's the difference between these two command? is it cause the ship move slowly???

Here is the code:

`bullet.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import pygame 

class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,setting,char):
        super().__init__()
        pic=pygame.image.load("../image/bullet.jpg").convert_alpha()
        self.mellon=pygame.transform.smoothscale(pic,(30,80))
        self.rect=self.mellon.get_rect()
#        self.rect=pygame.Rect(0,0,setting.bullet_w,setting.bullet_h)
        self.rect.centerx=char.ship_rect.centerx
        self.rect.top=char.ship_rect.top
        self.color=setting.bullet_c
        self.speed=setting.bullet_s
        self.y=float(self.rect.centery)
    def move_bullet(self):
        self.y -= self.speed
        self.rect.y= self.y
    def draw_bullet(self,setting):
        setting.screen.blit(self.mellon,self.rect)
        #pygame.draw.rect(setting.screen,self.color,self.rect)
    def blit_bullet(self,bullets,setting):
        for bullet in bullets.sprites():
             setting.screen.blit(bullet.mellon,bullet.rect)
             #pygame.draw.rect(setting.screen,bullet.color,bullet.rect)
             bullet.y -= bullet.speed
             bullet.rect.y=bullet.y
        for bullet in bullets:
            if bullet.rect.y <= 10:
                bullets.remove(bullet)
```

`ship.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import pygame

class Ship():
    def __init__(self,screen,setting):
        bk=pygame.image.load("../image/muha.png").convert()
        self.bkg=pygame.transform.smoothscale(bk,(setting.w,setting.h))
        temp=pygame.image.load("../image/title.jpg").convert_alpha()
        self.ship=pygame.transform.smoothscale(temp,(200,200))
        self.screen=screen
        self.screen_rect=screen.get_rect()
        self.ship_rect=self.ship.get_rect()
        
        

        self.ship_rect.center=self.screen_rect.center
        self.ship_rect.bottom=self.screen_rect.bottom
       
        self.x=float(self.ship_rect.centerx)
        self.y=float(self.ship_rect.centery)

    def blit_screen(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.bkg,(0,0))
    def blit_ship(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.ship,self.ship_rect)
```

`function.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import pygame
from bullet import Bullet
class Function():
     def __init__(self):
        self.moving_up   = False
        self.moving_down = False
        self.moving_left = False
        self.moving_right = False
     def event(self,bullets,setting,ship):      
         for event in pygame.event.get():
             if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                 sys.exit()
             elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                 if event.key ==pygame.K_z:
                     if len(bullets) < setting.bullet_n:
                        bullets.add(Bullet(setting,ship))
                 elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                     self.moving_up=True
                 elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                     self.moving_down=True
                 elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                     self.moving_left=True
                 elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                     self.moving_right=True
                 elif event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                        sys.exit()

             elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                 if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                     self.moving_up=False
                 elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                     self.moving_down=False
                 elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                     self.moving_left=False
                 elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                     self.moving_right=False

     def move(self,setting,ship):
         
         if self.moving_up == True and ship.ship_rect.top >= 0:
            ship.y -= setting.speed
         if self.moving_down == True and ship.ship_rect.bottom <= setting.h:
             ship.y += setting.speed
         if self.moving_left == True and ship.ship_rect.left >= 0:
             ship.x -= setting.speed
         if self.moving_right == True and ship.ship_rect.right <= setting.w:
             ship.x += setting.speed
         ship.ship_rect.centerx=ship.x
         ship.ship_rect.centery=ship.y
```

`alien.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import pygame as p
class Alien(p.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        pic=p.image.load("../image/ship.jpg").convert_alpha()
        self.alien=p.transform.smoothscale(pic,(100,100))
        self.alien_rect=self.alien.get_rect()
        self.alien_rect.x=(self.alien_rect.width)
        self.y = float(self.alien_rect.y)
    def create(self,setting,aliens):
        space=setting.w-(self.alien_rect.x)*2
        alien_number=int(space/(2*(self.alien_rect.width)))
        for number in range(alien_number):
            alien=Alien()
            alien.alien_rect.x=self.alien_rect.x+2*self.alien_rect.width*number
            aliens.add(alien)
    def move(self,setting):
        self.y += setting.alien_speed2
        self.alien_rect.y = self.y
    def blit(self,setting,aliens):
        for alien in aliens.sprites():
            setting.screen.blit(alien.alien,alien.alien_rect)
```

main script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys,os
import pygame 
from bullet     import Bullet
from ship       import Ship
from function   import Function
from alien      import Alien

class Setting():
    def __init__(self,width,height):
        self.w=width
        self.h=height
        self.flag=pygame.RESIZABLE
        self.color=(255,255,255)
        self.speed=1.5
        self.screen=pygame.display.set_mode((self.w,self.h),self.flag)
        pygame.display.set_caption("Muhaha")
        self.bullet_s=1.5
        self.bullet_w=5
        self.bullet_h=20
        self.bullet_n=10
        self.bullet_c=(0,0,0)
        self.alien_speed=1.5

def game():
    pygame.init()
    setting=Setting(1200,800)
    ship=Ship(setting.screen,setting)
    function=Function()
    bullet=Bullet(setting,ship)
    bullets=pygame.sprite.Group()
    alien=Alien()
    aliens=pygame.sprite.Group()         

    while True:
        function.event(bullets,setting,ship)
        
        ship.blit_screen()
        function.event(bullets,setting,ship)
        function.move(setting,ship)
        bullet.blit_bullet(bullets,setting)
        ship.blit_ship()
        alien.create(setting,aliens)
        alien.blit(setting,aliens)
        pygame.display.flip()
game()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `game()` function, you call `alien.create(setting,aliens)`
every frame.

After 1000 frames you'll have 1000 alien sprites.

You'll be rendering 1000 sprites every frame, and for each additional frame you'll have another sprite. So the game will become really slow.